# Can someone explain this C++ code?

Tags: c++

I am a new here. I do not understand the if statement: i==0, It eliminates repetition. How it works? Thanks.

```
vector<string>words;
for (string temp; cin >> temp;)
words.push_back(temp);
cout << "Number of words:" << words.size() << '\n';
sort(words);
for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
    if (i == 0 || words[i - 1] != words[i])
        cout << words[i] << '\n';
```

Comment: it prints word only if `words[i - 1] != words[i]` - it is different from the previous one. `i ==0` is just protection - since index 0 has no previous one.

Comment: Please pick up [a good beginner C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). And [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)!

Comment: Run it in a debugger with a set of known input strings (including some words used more than once), and see what happens while you single step though the last loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i equals 0, then you can't look words[i-1] because you can't do words[-1]

Furthermore, when you use || operator, if the first expression is true, the second expression is not checked

With `i == 0 || words[i - 1] != words[i]` you can print your first words because i equals 0 and the expression `words[i - 1] != words[i]` isn't checked and doesn't crash your program !
then with i different from 0, the first expresion isn't true and the second is checked.

---

For the unrepetition part :

Your array is sorted, so same words are one after another.
Then you have to check if the previous word isn't the same, you can print the word

---

How `words[i - 1] != words[i]` works :

for std::string, operators `==` and `!=` look for the length of each string, and each character in the string

[Comparison operator for std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)

Moreover, `words[i-1]` look for the previous words, and `words[i]` for the current one, to compare them.

So here, the expression is true if the two consecutives words aren't the same, in length and letters.
if you have words `dog` `cat` `cat` `cat_` in your array, `dog` is printed first (because of the `i == 0` part), the second word `cat` is printed, then the epression is false because the words are identical (`"cat" == "cat"`), and finaly, `cat_`is printed because different from `cat`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you explain how the words[i - 1] != words[i] work? If I typed: a dog a cat a rock

Comment: Tried ti explain it carfully, if it's unclear or if you have more questions, don't hesitate

Answer (score 0):

This program is first sorting all the words which are a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) of [strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), and prints only unique word.

`i==0` means the first word, Since you can't compare the first word with any previous so it will always be unique(from its previous words which doesn't exist)

`word[i-1]!=word[i]` check if the current word is different from previous the print that word.

`||` is a [Logical Or](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) operator.

Answer (score -1):

looks like your program prints the first word, and every other word that isn't repeated in a sorted list of words. If you're trying to look for unique words, try using [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).